# Python server instant disconnect

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

Here's the code giving me the issue:

```
def connect():
    s.listen(2)
    print("Server listening")
    conn,addr=s.accept()
    print("Connected with " + str(addr) + '\n')
    recv()

def recv():
    while 1:
        try:
            print("Starting try statement")
            data=conn.recv(1024)
            if data == "":
                print("No data")
                recv()
            else:
                print("Data")
                print(data.decode('UTF-8') + " -END")
                recv()
        except:
            print("No connection")
            connect()
        conn.close()
```

When I execute the code, it'll connect to the client and be ready to receive a message at any point. However, once it's executed this is what appears.

```
Server listening
Connected with ('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', xxxxx)

Starting try statement
No connection
Server listening
```

IP censored. Does anyone have a fix for this?

EDIT: Typo

CLIENT CODE (From TKinter GUI)

```
    s.connect((host,port))
        self.chatlog['state'] = NORMAL
        self.chatlog.insert(END, ("===CONNECTED TO SERVER\n"))
        self.chatlog['state'] = DISABLED
        self.chatlog.yview(END)
        self.conn=True
        print("Connected")
```

Comment: This code looks pretty broken. From within a 'while 1' loop, and are recursively calling yourself?

Comment: And what are the `conn` and `connect` names refer to? Could you provide a minimal runnable example?

Comment: Yes I'm using recursion, because once data has been received, I want the server ready to receive more.

Comment: This will never work -- classic infinite recursion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop

Comment: If you remove all recv() calls in your code, running recv() once should make it resume for ever. You probably want a time.sleep(someTime) in recv-loop.

Comment: The very first step should be to replace `except:` by something more helpful and to output the real exception. The way you do it, you are just blind. `except Exception, e:` should be the very first thing, and then `print e` in order to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.

Ya 'now that local conn what you are creating in function connect is not accessible from function recv? That is a reason for not reciving anything.

My solution using that code, without using classes and threads but with select and sys module is:

```
import sys
import select

def connect()
    s.listen(2)
    print('Sever listening')
    inputs = [s, sys.stdin]
    running = 1
    while running:
        i_rdy = select.select(inputs,[],[],1)[0]

        if s in i_rdy:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print ('Connected with ' + str(addr) + '\n')
            recv(conn)

        if sys.stdin in i_rdy:
            junk = std.stdin.readline()
            if junk.lstrip('\n') == 'exit':
                running = 0
                print('Closing server')

    s.close()

def recv(conn):
    while 1:
        try:
            print("Starting try statement")
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data == "":
                print("No data")

            else:
                print("Data")
                print(data.decode('UTF-8') + " -END")

        except:
            print("No connection")
            #traceback
            print(sys.exc_info)
            break
    try:
        conn.close()
    except:
        pass
```

As you can see can "exit" when u type exit to console but only when there is no active connection...

That why you should consider rewrite this to classes, it would be a lot easier to stop, not "ugly" and it could handle multiple connections.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually being helpful, and giving decent explanations. Others on this site have been less than helpful. I'll test this shortly, and if it works, I'll mark it as such.